# Integrate area undergraph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a graph and I need to get the area under it. possibly by integrating. But I don't have the equation of the function. I want to know how to get the area under it, how do i do this?

```
mass=[ 0.25877  0.26667  0.26667  0.27488  0.27488  0.28341  0.28341  0.29228
  0.29228  0.30149  0.30149  0.31103  0.31103  0.32089  0.32089  0.33104
  0.33104  0.34163  0.34163  0.35279  0.35279  0.36453  0.36453  0.37687
  0.37687  0.38979  0.38979  0.40321  0.40321  0.41709  0.41709  0.43138
  0.43138  0.44612  0.44612  0.46156  0.46156  0.47767  0.47767  0.49445
  0.49445  0.51206  0.51206  0.53047  0.53047  0.54963  0.54963  0.56964
  0.56964  0.59042  0.59042  0.61177  0.61177  0.63411  0.63411  0.65756
  0.65756  0.68194  0.68194  0.70721  0.70721  0.7332   0.7332   0.75966
  0.75966  0.78817  0.78817  0.81905  0.81905  0.85287  0.85287  0.88918
  0.88918  0.92732  0.92732  0.96587  0.96587  1.0048   1.0048   1.0438
  1.0438   1.0826   1.0826   1.1212   1.1212   1.1636   1.1636   1.2186
  1.2186   1.2744   1.2744   1.3422   1.3422   1.3565   1.3565   1.3659
  1.3659   1.3734   1.3734   1.3798 ]
Ni=[ 0.99628   0.99628   0.99628   0.99628   0.99628   0.99628   0.99628
  0.99628   0.99628   0.99628   0.99628   0.99628   0.99628   0.99628
  0.99628   0.99628   0.99628   0.99628   0.99628   0.99628   0.99628
  0.99628   0.99628   0.99628   0.988156  0.988156  0.98628   0.98628
  0.98628   0.98628   0.98628   0.98628   0.98628   0.98628   0.98628
  0.98628   0.98628   0.98628   0.98628   0.98628   0.98628   0.98628
  0.98628   0.98628   0.98628   0.98628   0.98628   0.98628   0.98628
  0.98628   0.98628   0.98628   0.93918   0.93918   0.93628   0.93628
  0.891223  0.891223  0.88228   0.88228   0.871528  0.871528  0.86728
  0.86728   0.476344  0.476344  0.335726  0.335726  0.11728   0.11728
  0.11728   0.11728   0.11728   0.11728   0.11728   0.11728   0.11728
  0.11728   0.11728   0.11728   0.012725  0.012725  0.        0.        0.
  0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
  0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.      ]

print mass
print Ni
plt.plot(mass,Ni)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `mass` and `Ni` are lists, I can suggest the `scipy` module integrate:

```
import scipy.integrate as integ
```

As the function you are using is defined by steps, you can not use Simpson integration algorithm. The basic trapezoid algorithm must work:

```
res = integ.trapz(Ni, mass)
```

I find `0.532721` using your data.

Comment: yes perfect, I was under the impression I also had to give a function in the scipy.intergrate I was wrong. Thanks you